# .Net user can not connect to php Webservice

Tags: php, .net, nginx, wsdl, nusoap

I have a php Webservice With this code :

```
require_once('nusoap.php');
require_once('gw.interface.php');

$namespace = 'www.mydomain.com';

$server = new soap_server();
$server->soap_defencoding = 'UTF-8';
$server->decode_utf8 = false;
$server->encode_utf8 = true;
$server->configureWSDL('smsserver', 'urn:smsserver');

$server->wsdl->addComplexType(
 'ListArray',
 'complexType',
 'array',
 '',
 'SOAP-ENC:Array',
  array(),
  array(
    array('ref'=>'SOAP-ENC:arrayType','wsdl:arrayType'=>'xsd:string[]')
  ),
  'xsd:string'
);

/**
 * SendSMS
 **/
$server->register('SendSMS', 
    array(
        'fromNum' => 'xsd:string',
        'toNum' => 'xsd:string',
        'messageContent' => 'xsd:string',
        'messageType' => 'xsd:string',
        'user' => 'xsd:string',
        'pass' => 'xsd:string'
    ), array('return' => 'xsd:string'),
    $namespace, 'SendSMS', 'rpc', 'encoded', 'send your sms');


function SendSMS($fromNum, $toNum, $messageContent, $messageType, $user, $pass)
{
    return gwi::sendsms($fromNum, $toNum, $messageContent, $messageType, $user, $pass); 
}

/**
 * GetCredit
 **/
$server->register('GetCredit', 
    array(
        'user' => 'xsd:string',
        'pass' => 'xsd:string'
    ), array('return' => 'xsd:string'),
    $namespace, 'GetCredit', 'rpc', 'encoded', 'check your credit');


function GetCredit($user, $pass)
{
    return gwi::GetCredit($user, $pass);
}

/**
 * GetStatus
 **/
$server->register('GetStatus', 
    array(
        'user' => 'xsd:string',
        'pass' => 'xsd:string',
        'batchid' => 'xsd:string',
        'unique_ids' => 'tns:ListArray'
    ), array('return' => 'xsd:string'),
    $namespace, 'GetStatus', 'rpc', 'encoded', 'get messages delivery status');


function GetStatus($user, $pass, $batchid, $uniqs)
{
    return gwi::GetStatus($user, $pass, $batchid, $uniqs);
}


$server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
```

The Problem is this code worked before i change my webserver from **apache to nginx.**

**i used this code on another server and was ok. the same Code same request.**

So when a .Net client wants to connect to My webservice it can Detect My Webservice.
 but When it wants to call of one of my methods 
get this error in .net :

```
{"The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found."}
```

and the client code For Example in Vb

```
        Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim x As ServiceReference2.
smsserverPortTypeClient = New ServiceReference2.smsserverPortTypeClient()
        Dim result As String = "-"

        result = x.GetCredit("test", "123456") + " ";


        MsgBox(result)



End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the WS as a Web Reference on your .NET project, instead of a Service Reference? As far as I know, a PHP webservice has to be treated as a web service instead of a common one, as ASMX does.

To do so, follow these simple steps:

1. Right click on your project in the Solution Explorer.
2. Click on "Add Service Reference"
3. Click the "Advanced" button on the bottom-left of the dialog window (I'm sorry if the button has another name, I'm translating these steps from my spanish GUI)
4. Go again to the bottom-left corner and click the "Add web reference" button.
5. Add the webservice URL on the field on top, give it a name in the field to the right, and voilá!

The process, then, should be more simple: you use the methods of the WS using the name you gave to the service as a namespace.

I hope this suits you. Good luck!